# Install Birdfont on elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

I installed Birdfont via the Appcenter on elementary OS!
Installation works, but the program doesn´t start.

On starting in the Terminal I get the following message:

```
birdfont: error while loading shared libraries: libxmlbird.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

It will be fixed in future versions, here is a workaround:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libxmlbird.so.1.3 libxmlbird.so.1.0
```